# Is it idiomatic to write “have been having a holiday”?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

Is it idiomatic to use "have been having a holiday"?

> We have had a vacation since last week. / We have been on vacation since last week.
>
> We have been having a vacation since last week.

Are they the same in their meaning? How would be better to say it?

Comment: Are you looking for a specifically British or American answer?  The usage of *holiday* varies a bit between them, I think.

Comment: Please write both.

Comment: The usual expression is _to be on holiday/vacation_. As a British English speaker, I might possibly say "I once had a holiday in Norway", meaning that I had once gone on a holiday  trip there.